# Reading Frame Buffer Denied even after signing with system permissions

Tags: android-ndk, framebuffer

I signed my app with system permissions and I am using ndk to read from /dev/graphics/fb0. But I get a permissions denied error. Aren't system permissions suppose to allow you to do anything ?? 
Thank you for your time.